# Purpose of the :root pseudo class

Tags: css

I just found the `:root` pseudo class.

> The :root CSS pseudo-class matches the root element of a tree representing the document. Applied to HTML, :root represents the  element and is identical to the selector html, except that its specificity is higher.

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aroot)

What exactly is it used for? Why would anyone ever use it aside from higher specificity when you can just use the `html` selector?

Comment: What if it's an SVG document? An XHTML document? `:root` is thus then primarily an abstraction (ignoring specificity).

Comment: For one, `base.css` could apply `html { ... }` and `theme.css` could apply `:root { }` to override (without the need for `!important` or other hacks)

Comment: @user2864740 Intereseting point. Can you post an answer explanding on that? I think this is the real reason.

Comment: "While most often used to style web pages and interfaces written in HTML and XHTML, the language can be applied to any kind of XML document, including plain XML, SVG and XUL" [CSS Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)

Comment: @user3618088 I don't have anything more to add, but someone with different experiences using it will I hope!

Comment: Just to give you an idea of what can be done, check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tJd3r/) where the root node has become an element with the name "user3618088" and the html element has become a child of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer here is:

> except that its specificity is higher.

### And why does it matter?

In a normal CSS scenario, if you have something like this:

```
html {
    background-color: red;
}

html {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

You will get the blue background, because it's evaluated last. You can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xZ2Gw/).

But, if you have this instead:

```
:root {
    background-color: red;
}

html {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

You'll get the red background. You can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xZ2Gw/1/).

Imagine a scenario where you import several libraries and some of then set some properties on the `html` that you want to get rid of. You can define your properties as `!important`, you can organize your imports so what you want is evaluated last or you can use the `:root` selector.

---

### Others Scenarios

As pointed by @user2864740 and @13ruce1337, CSS is not only applied to HTML, but it can be applied to [any kind of XML document, including plain XML, SVG and XUL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets). The `:root` pseudo class will select the root of other types of document correctly.

Comment: ..and if you want even higher specificity, you could use `html:root`. http://jsfiddle.net/jtS6j/

Comment: Do you mind touching on some of the topics discussed in the comments above? That would make an excellent answer!